# How to upgrade kubectl server version

Tags: docker, kubernetes

On Windows 10 Pro, I installed docker and the Kubernetes cli. I upgraded the kubectl.exe to version 1.15 by replacing the old one in the docker folder. When I run “kubectl version”, it shows the client version as 1.15, but the server version still shows as 1.10. How can I upgrade the server version to 1.15?

Comment: Since it's embedded into the Docker app you're dependent on Docker to do the upgrade.  [Docker for Mac has the same issue.](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/3663)

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to SO !, I assume you are using Kubernetes cluster, that is available as an installation option of Docker Desktop for Windows. In that case you cannot easily upgrade your Kubernetes cluster (server side), as its particular version is bundled with Docker Desktop installer (e.g. [Docker Community Edition 2.0.0.2 2019-01-16](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/release-notes/) comes with Kubernetes 1.10.11 version).

If you want to have a full control over Kubernetes version (server side/control plane) please check [minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/learning-environment/minikube/) tool, which lets you specify it by adding '`--kubernetes-version`' argument (`minikube start --kubernetes-version v1.15.0`). With minikube there is still an option to [re-use](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/docs/reusing_the_docker_daemon.md) the Docker daemon inside the VM (started with 'minikube start command' in the background).

Comment: Your link for reusing the docker daemon is dead.

Comment: This worked "minikube start --kubernetes-version v1.15.0" Thanks @Nepomucen

Answer (score 2):

You need to upgrade kubernetes control plane.

you can use below commands to upgrade k8s cluster if the cluster is setup using kubeadm

```
export VERSION="1.15"
export ARCH=amd64
wget https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v${VERSION}/bin/linux/amd64/kubeadm > /usr/bin/kubeadm
chmod a+rx /usr/bin/kubeadm

kubeadm upgrade apply ${VERSION}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23498373)

Comment: included steps to upgrade the cluster